# argparse, but for stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Is there a way to use Python's `argparse` library against user input from stdin instead of on `sys.argv`? In other words, I want the program to already be running, and be able to use `argparse` to handle when the user types something like `web-server stop`.